# Why can't I use '0' as an _id with mongoDB and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of objects representing folders. I would like to let the user create folders as they please with the constraint that the app will create a 'root' folder (object) and I would like to control the _id property for this folder. according to the [mongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field) I should be able to set the _id field but when I try I get an error:

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "0" at path "_id"
```

The mongo docs say the _id can be any [BSON data type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) other than array so I don't understand why '0' is not valid. Why can't I use '0' as an _id?

To be clear, I would like mongoDB to generate an id for all other cases other than the root folder.

folder schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const constants = require('../config/constants');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const FolderSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: [true, 'Folder must have a user'],
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    dateCreated: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    lastUpdated: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    parentId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  },
);

FolderSchema.index({ name: 'text' });

// eslint-disable-next-line func-names
FolderSchema.virtual('id').get(function () {
  return this._id.toHexString();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Folder', FolderSchema);
```

Comment: Could you include the schema for your model?

Comment: @caffeinated.tech done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare in your schema what format the `_id` should have.
Mongoose defaults it to BSON ObjectId, but this can be overwritten as per [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id): (emphasis mine)

> You can also overwrite Mongoose's default _id with your own _id. Just be careful: Mongoose will refuse to save a document that doesn't have an _id, **so you're responsible for setting _id if you define your own _id path.**
>
> `const schema = new Schema({ _id: Number });`
> `const Model = mongoose.model('Test', schema);`
>
> `const doc = new Model();`
> `await doc.save(); // Throws "document must have an _id before saving"`
>
> `doc._id = 1;`
> `await doc.save(); // works`

Applying this to your schema:

```
const FolderSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: [true, 'Folder must have a user'],
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    dateCreated: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    lastUpdated: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    parentId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  },
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I believe what I want to do may not be possible. I only want to specify the _id for exactly 1 folder, the root folder, for each user and have mongoDB generate it for all others. And now that I think about it, that would not work if users folders are stored together in the same db because there would need to be more than one folder with id 0. Maybe it would be better to have another property on my model like a boolean 'isRoot'. I guess this would have to be the standard approach over trying to manipulate an id.

Comment: @regexAgainstTheMachine Yes, the boolean approach is more usual. You don't want one field with multiple types as it will only cause bugs in the long run.

Comment: Sounds good. I accepted your answer as it is the right approach to override the _id field. Thanks again.